# What's the difference between verbs pee and piss?

Tags: difference, vocabulary

I wonder what's the difference between these two verbs given that the dictionaries translate it the same way?

Comment: This question seems to come up a lot on ELL: http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=pee+piss

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Piss* would be considered more vulgar, *pee* would be considered more mild and informal.

It's common to ask a young child, "Do you need to go pee?" I wouldn't ask a young child, "Do you need to take a piss?"

The words also have differences in how they are used, as those questions show. You can *go pee*, and you can *take a piss*. (Other variants may apply, with differences in how standard they might be. I wouldn't say that *take a pee* or *go piss* are unacceptable, but they don't seem as common.)

*Piss* can also be used a slang verb. To *get pissed* is to get very angry. (For example: *Joe was pissed about his traffic ticket.*)

Comment: In British English, *pissed* can mean 'drunk' ([Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pissed)).

Comment: @snailboat - Maybe I should have put a disclaimer in my answer, but I'm not suggesting my answer is comprehensive. (I also didn't delve into the exclamation "Piss off!" for example.)

Comment: Oh, no disclaimer necessary!  I was just trying to add a little extra information :-)

Comment: Indeed **pissed off at** may also mean **angry with**

Comment: But OP asked about the 'verbs' and you described 'nouns'. 'go pee, take a piss'.

Comment: @MaulikV I think what J.R. said applies pretty well to both the noun and verb uses.  In any case, to be precise: they're verbs following *go* (in the quasi-serial verb construction).  *Take a piss* is a light verb construction in which the actual verb is *take*, but the noun *piss* carries the actual meaning.  It corresponds to the heavy verb *piss*.  (Learners probably don't need to worry about these distinctions.)

Comment: When the OP is confused about the *basic* difference in those two verbs, understanding *quasi-serial verb construction* and *mild verb, heavy verb* could be of 'too much information'. Again, it's MO though. @snailboat

Comment: Let me rephrase, then, since it seems I was unclear.  I think J.R.'s answer is fine, and we don't need to worry too much about whether individual uses are noun or verb uses in this case.  We can make the technical distinction between the two, but it won't change the answer much, so I don't think learners need to worry about it.  (If anyone does, they can always ask a separate question about that sort of technical detail.)

Comment: @MaulikV - You bring up a good point, one that shows that an O.P. should not be too [quick](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307) to select an answer. That said, I agree with what snailboat was trying to say – _go pee_ works like a phrasal verb of sorts. Consider: _A bear eats in the woods. A bear sleeps in the woods. A bear goes pee in the woods._ Same with _take a piss_; _take_ is not a verb with _piss_ as its object, but "take a piss" functions together as a single verb. Thankfully, "I need to take a piss" is not grammatically the same as "I need to take an aspirin."

Comment: That's new to me! Thanks @J.R. Is it the same with *I need to take a break*, how do we differentiate then? *Take a [something]* where something does not work as a noun! Ah, that makes a good question.

Answer (score 3):

In my (American) experience:

"Piss" is a word used by men, and by boys who were raised by men.

"Pee" is a word used by women, by girls, and by boys who were raised by women.

"Urinate" is a word used by doctors, nurses, and other medical professionals.

Comment: Don't think gender has anything to do with it.

Comment: In my American experience, yours is not the only experience and ascribes an overly strict gendered division

Comment: -1, I would say this view is not representative of American usage of these words in general.

Comment: Down with piss then

Answer (score 3):

to pee= ( informal) to pass liquid waste from your body

to piss= ( impolite) to get rid of waste liquid from your body

to wee=(spoken) to urinate [ this word is used mainly by and to children ]

to urinate=(formal) to get rid of urine from your body

Answer (score 2):

Both terms are informal and considered vulgar slang. Piss is somewhat onomatopoeic and comes from the Old French "pisser" (PIS - ay) meaning to urinate.

"Pee" is just the first letter of "piss" and meant to soften it and make it more polite. This may be a reason some associate the use with children and the female gender.